# Why is my calculating a percentage not working correctly when I am dividing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to see what percentage of customers paying LL and the percentage of customers that are paying LP. For example I have 1 customer in LL and 1 in LP so percentage should be 50% in Cust_LL_Pct and Cust_LP_Pct. I have tried using a ISNULL, and set it as 0, but that didn't fix the problem. The Pct Columns are giving be only 0 and 1, nothing in between. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baa4v.png)

```
[SELECT
 b.country_IBS AS Country_IBS_LL
,b.Sku AS SKU_LL
,b.TY_Sales_USD_LL 
,b.TY_Qty_LL
,b.TY_Sales_USD_LL / (b.TY_Qty_LL) AS ASP_LL
,b.Customer_Count_LL
,a.country_IBS AS Country_IBS_LP
,a.Sku AS SKU_LP
,a.Total_LP_Sales
,a.Total_LP_Qty
,a.Total_LP_Sales / a.Total_LP_Qty AS ASP_LP
,a.Customer_Count_LP
,SUM(ISNULL(b.Customer_Count_LL,0) + ISNULL(a.Customer_Count_LP,0)) AS SKU_Total_Customer
,ISNULL(b.Customer_Count_LL,0) / SUM(ISNULL(b.Customer_Count_LL,0) + ISNULL(a.Customer_Count_LP,0)) AS Cust_LL_Pct
,ISNULL(a.Customer_Count_LP,0) / SUM(ISNULL(b.Customer_Count_LL,0) + ISNULL(a.Customer_Count_LP,0)) AS Cust_LP_Pct
--INTO #temp6
FROM #temp2 a
FULL JOIN #temp5 b
ON a.Sku = b.Sku
AND a.country_IBS = b.country_IBS
GROUP BY
b.country_IBS
,b.Sku
,b.TY_Sales_USD_LL
,b.TY_Qty_LL
,b.TY_Sales_USD_LL / b.TY_Qty_LL 
,b.Customer_Count_LL
,a.country_IBS
,a.Sku
,a.Total_LP_Sales
,a.Total_LP_Qty
,a.Total_LP_Sales / a.Total_LP_Qty 
,a.Customer_Count_LP][1]
```

Comment: Aside: Percent usually involves multiplying by 100 so that the results are in the range 0..100 rather than 0..1. If applied to the [dividend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Introduction) you would get a more useful result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is integer division. When both operands are integers, SQL Server produces an integer result: for example, `3/2` yields `1`, not `1.5`.

You need to force decimal context for the operation, for example by multiplying with a (dummy) decimal value, like:

```
1.0 * b.TY_Sales_USD_LL / b.TY_Qty_LL AS ASP_LL
```

I would not recommend using `isnull(..., 0)` for the right operand of a division: if the value is actually `null`, you get a division by `0`, which is a fatal error. On the other hand, dividing by `null` yields `null`, which does not fail, and seems more relevant.